# Position DIVs in same place, toggle them

Tags: css, html, positioning

I'm having a little issue with couple of DIVs.

I need two DIVs to be positioned in exactly same place, and toggle them. As one div disappear, another should appear. This I will do using jQuery toggle().

The issue is that both DIVs should be part of the page flow and positioned exactly the same way. How I would achieve that?

So, there is some previous div, that occupies some place, has relative positioning and non-fixed sizes (dependent on window measures)

```
<div class="header">
... </div>
```

Then my div

```
<div id="galleria" style="height:700px;width:920px; margin:0 auto; border:1px solid green;   ">
 ... </div>
```

and other my DIV

```
<div id="aboutDiv" >
This is ABOUT
</div>
```

Two later divs should occupy the same place. What positioning tags I could use?

The design adjusts to the window size due to flexible element  -- very first DIV "header", so no absolute positioning is possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just put them one after another

```
<div id="galleria" style="height:700px;width:920px; margin:0 auto; border:1px solid green;   "> ... </div>
<div id="aboutDiv" >
This is ABOUT
</div>
```

both should be positioned `relative` , when one is hidden then other will move up and they will be in the same place - as long as you are using toggle to always have one hidden and one shown

Answer (score 0):

You either need a relatively positioned parent container with absolutely positioned children, or hide one and show the other when its faded out completely